# drawing semicircle with the plot command in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've tried drawing the lower half of the unit circle with tikz using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [domain=-1: 1] plot(\x, {(-1)*sqrt{1-\x*\x}});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, the output is unexpected in two ways: the graph looks more like a **parabola** than a circle and it is **concave** down! (I figured how to get the desired graph with the arc command.)

As a naive question coming from a newcomer to this site, how do you save your tikz outputs to upload here? Do you clip them from the pdf file? (I assume there should be easier methods that I'm not familiar with.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is the wrong braces for `sqrt`. It expects parentheses instead of curly braces. The parsing of the formula has apparently vanished the curly braces and the formula had become: `-1 * sqrt 1 - \x*\x` = -1 - x<sup>2</sup>, indeed a parabola.

With parentheses:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [blue, domain=-1: 1, samples=25] plot(\x, {-sqrt(1-\x*\x)});
\draw [red, xshift=2.5cm, domain=180:360] plot(\x:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The blue half circle has the problem of the starting and ending line. Because of the large slope, there are not so many sample points on the left and right. A workaround for a smoother curve is to increase the number of samples.

A more efficient way is used for the red half circle. It uses polar coordinates. This also simplifies the formula here.